# Please enable SQL Language syntax highlighting

Tags: support, feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Does the SQL language hint not work on this site (perhaps because it is in beta)?  I tried adding `<!-- language: sql -->` to [a question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1817/nest-select-in-insert), as per the [meta information on language hints](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79785/syntax-highlighting-what-about-answering-with-a-different-language-than-the-one), but it didn’t change the formatting at all.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Here's a [more recent example](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5989/is-from-table-t1-acceptable-practice/5991#5991) of syntax highlighting inaction.

Comment: related request for a global setting [here](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/774/can-we-have-language-all-sql-applied-by-default)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have added default style selections to a few of the tags that had no selection before.  Let me know if there are others that appear to need styling.

Styling was added to the following tags:

[sql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql) 
[mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql)
[stored-procedures](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stored-procedures)

Moderators do have the ability to change the default lang for highlighting per tag - just visit the tag info page:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/sql/info

---

[image: tag info language selector]

Comment: Well when we added the manual hint it did not work. What more needs to be done specifically?

Comment: @jcole as Geoff said, you need to click through on the tag info link and look for this text `Code Language (used for syntax highlighting): [list of languages] [save]`

Comment: So it turns out the reason it never worked initially was because it wasn't turned on per-site when this site asked for it (got overlooked), nor is it turned on by default per-site at launch.

Comment: My [last answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6310/how-to-show-table-titles-from-a-database-with-a-simple-sql-query/6314#6314) shows syntax highlighting just the way I would expect and hope - ie *nearly right* :-) Thanks for the update.