# Syntax highlighting problems

Tags: discussion, support, tagging

In followup to [Please enable SQL Language syntax highlighting](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/please-enable-sql-language-syntax-highlighting) if you find a tag that needs syntax highlighting and it doesn't have it, or if you have cases where the syntax highlighting is unusual, please add an answer to this Q and we'll sort it out right away.

Or hit a mod up in the [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-clustered-index).

Comment: A note, code in SQL Server tags, phrases inside of [] brackets aren't treated like identifiers, as you can see in this question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6289/query-data-from-multiple-linked-remote-databases technically in that case [Table] is an identifier, not a keyword. Don't know if we follow bracket notation though, as only SQL Server does it.

Comment: Is that worth following up on, do you think @BenBrocka because we could always ask SEI to see if they can manipulate the lang-formatter, or we could backtrace it to the google repos and try to get the change fixed there.

Comment: the specific issue isn't super-crucial but it's not reading SQL Server code like SQL Server does, if I notice any more oddities I'll get a list and then maybe we should bring it up. I don't know how big a deal it is to change anything so I hesitate to suggest changes just for SQL Server, I don't even know if SQL Server code is read differently.

Comment: Those things are usually handled by a regex, so we would have to figure out the regex pattern as well I imagine. Opening and closing braces are also always hard to figure out properly.

Comment: Should be pretty simple since it's the only thing SQL Server uses brackets for, `\[.*?\]` is a start of the pattern but it selects the brackets too.

Comment: I rather meant "without interrupting the other parsing that is going on" since I haven't ever looked at that source

Comment: yeah, that I have no idea about

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3110/sql-2005-can-we-determine-how-much-the-rebuild-index-maintenance-job-can-grow-da/3111#3111) has some SQL that is not highlighted.  Should we enable highlighting for all of the [sql-server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server) tags?

Comment: I shall look, it was working this morning on other questions with [tag:sql-server] so that shouldn't be the case.

Answer (score 1):

If this thread isn't just for SQL highlighting, I'll throw [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6191/how-do-you-identify-innodb-table-corruption/6355#6355) as 'unusual'

I know syntax highlighting isn't perfect, and I don't know how it works in answers, but it's reading my script as comment.

Comment: I've added the <!-- language: lang-bsh --> hint to fix this one - is that better?

Comment: @jack Ah-hah, so that's how it's done. Yup, better

Comment: This thread is for all highlighting, and when it comes to bash scripts and the like in an answer that's not the same language as the Q, you're probably going to have to force it with the lang tag as Jack did.